# Halt loading of data until gps coordinates are acquired

Tags: android, gps, android-loadermanager

I'm getting the current GPS coordinates as per [this](http://developer.android.com/training/location/retrieve-current.html) tutorial. And loading my data like [this](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/LoaderManager.html).

How can I delay loading my data until the GPS coordinates are acquired? Or in another way, how can I trigger loading of my data after the coordinates are acquired?

Answer (score 0):

If I were you I would have used a simple SQLite database to record the  coordinates. Read this tutorial here:

http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidSQLite/article.html

After that , implement a Location Listener in your class, create an instance of location manager . Use the location manager and request for location updates , by registering the location listener. When you've implemented the location listener , you would have implemented few methods "unimplemented methods" like onLocationChanged(Location loc). In this method, you can give your database code you've learnt in your tutorial to log the location data.

This is actually very simple, even though it might sound complicated initially, I'll try and give some code for you to understand , I'm away frommy laptop right now !

Comment: The thing is my data is sorted by distance to the current location. So I simply don't want to load my data before I get the current location.